# Java Manifest not working on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, manifest.mf

I made an jar program "AbLauncher v0.1.0.jar" and It ran it successfully.

but when I gave it to the Windows 8 user,

he says that he got this error while running on cmd:

Cannot Find or Load main class AbLauncher

But, the main class specified by Manifest was launch.Launch, not 'AbLauncher'.

'AbLauncher' was just the jar name: AbLauncher v0.1.0.jar.

Can Anyone Explain why this error happens?

Manifest file was:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: launcher.Launcher
```

File Directory setting was

```
form/
launcher/
(launcher/Launcher.class is main class)
META-INF/
resource/
server/
settings/
util/
```

Of course other class files exists here, but i couldn't write all of them...
and there's nothing like: AbLauncher.class

Comment: show the manifest file..

Comment: that looks ok, can you also show the folder structure within the jar?